# Multiple input folders for hadoop mapreduce and s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce

I currently have a bucket on AWS S3, let's just call it "bucketX" for simplicity. within BucketX, there are 4 folders:

data, docs1, docs2, docs3.

I want to run a HDFS mapreduce job on all directories except "data", using docs1, docs2, and docs3 as input directories, and some other output directory.

I am a bit confused as to how I can configure this in the driver.

I know

```
 FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
```

exists, but how specifically can I manually configure the 3 input paths to be used? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcards -

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("s3://bucketX/docs*"));
```